# Azure DevOps: Creating custom checklist work item

Tags: azure-devops

We are using an inherited Agile process which we want to customize in the following way:

Add a custom work item type, which is shown as checklist item for a *feature* in a kanban board. As seen in the [agile work-item hierarchy documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/get-started/plan-track-work?view=azure-devops&tabs=agile-process) the default child-items for a *feature* are *user-story* and *bug* and they are shown in the kanban board as expected (for reference, see [checklist item documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/boards/add-task-checklists?view=azure-devops)).

However what I can't manage to do is to add a work item type which can be added as child to a feature and which is then shown in the same fashion.

Any advice if this is feasible and where to configure this relation between *feature* and *my-custom-work-item*?

Comment: Tasks inside of user stories are also not shown as checklist items. Even though that is the example used in the documentation. I can only see features containings user-stories and bugs, but when I switch to user-story board view I cannot see the child-tasks

Comment: Found the solution to this comment. Go to the user stories board > Settings (gear icon on upper right) > Annotations and enable "Task"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Any advice if this is feasible and where to configure this relation
> between feature and my-custom-work-item?

You may add this reference on the Backlog Levels: [Edit, rename, or delete a portfolio backlog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/customize-process-backlogs-boards?view=azure-devops#edit-rename-or-delete-a-portfolio-backlog)

Add your `my-custom-work-item` to User Story Level.

Comment: Hi Shamrai, thank you, this is what I wanted!

Comment: Could you also tell me how to resolve the comment below the post?

Comment: @Bat pls, rise another question and add screenshots of or User  Stories.

Comment: Found it out myself. Thanks very much for your help!